# mysql_insert_id() to view value of last inserted records

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I have a PHP script that inserts data into a mysql database. The table has an auto increment column.

I want to use the mysql_insert_id() function to get teh value of the last inserted record.

For some reason this is returning the value 0 where the autoid column has a value of 300037.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

my code snippet is below:

```
$sqlinsertdelivery="INSERT INTO deliverydetails (`LoadID1`,`deliveryroute`,`source`,`destination`,`route`,`CollectionArea1`, `CollectionArea2`, `CollectionArea3`, `CollectionArea4`, `CollectionDate`, `collectiontime`, `Destination1`, `Destination2`, `Destination3`, `Destination4`, `ArrivalDate`, `ArrivalTime`, `DeliveryCreationDateTime`, `DeliveryCreatedBy`,`comments`,`trailertype`) 
 VALUES
 ($loadnumber,'$route1','Hulamin','$dest1','$_SESSION[sessionrouteid]','$_POST[dispatchid1]','$_POST[dispatchid2]','$_POST[dispatchid3]','$_POST[dispatchid4]','$_POST[coldatetime]','$_POST[deltime]','$_POST[drop1]','$_POST[drop2]','$_POST[drop3]','$_POST[drop4]','$_POST[arrivedatetime]','$_POST[arrivetime]',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$session->username','$_POST[comments]','$_POST[vehicletype]')
 ";
  if (!mysql_query($sqlinsertdelivery,$con))
   {
   die('Error with insert statement: ' . mysql_error());
   }


$delid = mysql_insert_id();
echo $delid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long shot, but first try replacing `mysql_insert_id();` with `mysql_insert_id($con);`

On a side note, PLEASE tell me this is code that will **not** be in production.

Comment: Can you please add to your post above the database table CREATE SQL?

Comment: Daniel, apologies! your solution was 100% correct and is working perfectly.

Comment: I want to stress that your query is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Please use sanitation techniques on all variables going into a mysql query. In addition to that, if you plan on using the `mysql_`* functions please use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all variables going into the query. Be safe out there!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I was researching this today and will sanitize the code as I learn more, Thanks for the help, much apprecaited.